# Which component of MV should transform raw data into user friendly format?

Tags: c++, qt

There is a structure that holds raw data (consider int) and a gui that should visualize this data. Gui part consists of a few models and and a few standard views (table and tree). The value should be presented either as a string or as a picture depend on user choice. There are some additional difficulties: in some cases the text is different for different elements - i.e., for the same column 0 normally means "Ok", but for a particular element it should be printed as "Yes", also depend on a user choice some columns should not print text for 0 values at all, living a cell empty and don't clutter the table; next, sometimes cell should show two values - e.g., current value and requested - something like "Yes -> No". This also applies to the case when user wants to see icons.

I see two options:

1. The model forms string text itself and store it somewhere (in the model item may be). The model also forms composite icon from base icons if it is needed. In that scenario I can use standard delegate and just use standard roles reimplementing `QAbstractItemModel::data()` method.
2. Reimplement delegates' `paint()` method (actually I need to reimplement delegates anyway because I need custom editors like QComboBox). The delegate can get any information it needs through the model and custom roles in `paint()` method and form the string or complex icon itself. As a suboption, I suppose, it's possible for a model to compose needed information itself, like returning `std::tuple<int /*value*/, int /*requested value*/, int /*source element type*/, bool /*text or icon*/>` in `data()` method for Qt::DisplayRole.

Update: I want add one thought about second option. Presumably delegates were introduced to handle the work of representing data. One of the consequences of that is the flexibility delegates can give. If you want to see a raw number in some column, you can just leave the default delegate, if you want some additional info presented in a cell you can set a special delegate for that specific column. And it seems you don't need even touch the model or something else.

Comment: You should handle in you `QAbstractItemModel::data()` function of your custom model and return appropriate values depending on the column and role values.

Comment: That's one of my suggestions. But I would by glad for any clarifications. Some examples I had found in the internet use the opposite approach -  model just gives a value (i.e. an int), and delegate handles it's visualisation as a string. In that case transformation is handled by the class (delegate) separated from other logic, isn't it's a way should be preferred? If a model would handle data access, data transformation, user settings for these transformations, structure changing - it can become difficult and cumbersome easily.

Comment: In your case, when it's about customizing text and icons, I would go with already proposed approach using model. That's why different `Qt::ItemDataRole`s exist in Qt. If you want custom editing, or some non standard representation of data, such as progress bars, charts etc. I would recommend delegate. I, personally, don't see difficulties in using models. From the other hand, drawing text in delegate's paint event is even harder and overkill, IMO.

Comment: I was afraid of this kind of answer). You say my situation can be reduced to the standard solution - I think that's true. But your comment looks a little bit contradictory for me. As I said, I need custom editors; "concatenating" two values seems to me more "non standard" representation rather than progress bar. I tried paint simple strings myself, it doesn.t seems to be overkill. Most default things like font or alignment can be configured using `QStyleOptionViewItem`. Anyway, thanks for comment.